# save result rsponse from another application code to your application

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have code in Django application for generating and download excel files, but now I created another application in the same project.

Now I want to save that result excel file in the project directory itself.

Here I am trying with the below code but I am not able to get any response.

```
 from xlwt import workbook
 def invoice_report(request, slug):
     .......
     .......
     elif 'download' in request.GET:
         if str(request.GET.get('download')).lower() == 'true':
             response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
             response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Report.xls"'
             wb.save(response)
             return response  


 def result_report(request):
     mutable_value = request.GET._mutable
     print(mutable_value)
     request.GET._mutable = True
     request.GET['download'] = 'xls'
     request.GET['download'] = 'true'
     request.GET._mutable = mutable_value
     result_response = invoice_report(request,slug)
     if result_response:
         file = open(folder_name + '/' + str(aircraft.msn) +'report.xls', 'wb')
         file.write(result_response.rendered_content)
         file.close()
         return response
```

Comment: What error you are getting

Comment: i am able to generate .xl file but its not opening  and while testing i am  type of response is bytes response @YugandharChaudhari

Answer (score 0):

Try the following fix to solve cors error

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [ 'DELETE', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'PUT', ]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [ 'accept', 'accept-encoding', 'authorization', 'content-type', 'dnt', 'origin', 'user-agent', 'x-csrftoken', 'x-requested-with', ]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [ 'http://localhost:5000', ]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to post here, nor what your edits here have been. It does not appear this is in any way related to your original question.